# C# 3 argument checkbox DataView.RowFilter Filtering with multiple columns

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, rowfilter

I have small problem, i dont know how realise more arguments filter.
I have 3 checkbox, Name, Category and Date(start,end)

Here is my code, individyaly for 1 check it work fine

```
if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
            {
                views.RowFilter = "[Produkta nosaukums] like '%" + textBox3.Text.ToString() + "%'";
            }
            if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
            {
                views.RowFilter = "[Kateg.] like '%" + comboBox4.Text.ToString() + "%'";
            }
            if (checkBox3.Checked == true)
            {
                views.RowFilter = "[Derīguma termiņš] >= #" + dateTimePicker3.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "# and [Derīguma termiņš] <= #" + dateTimePicker4.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "#";
            }
```

Problem is when i want more arguments search, like name and category.
I tryed here is my code, but only work for category name ignored :/

```
if (checkBox1.Checked == false & checkBox2.Checked == false & checkBox3.Checked == false)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns.Remove(editButton);
                dataGridView1.Columns.Remove(deleteButton);
                LOADALL();
            }


            if (checkBox1.Checked == true & checkBox2.Checked == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(comboBox4.Text.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(textBox3.Text.ToString());
                views.RowFilter = "[Kateg.] like '%" + comboBox4.Text.ToString() + "%' and [Produkta nosaukums] like '%" + textBox3.Text.ToString() + "%'";
            }
```

What i want is, filter add another checkbox too.

1. Check1, check2, check3
2. true  true  true dont realized
3. true false true dont realized
4. false true true dont realized
5. true true false dont work tryed
6. true false false work
7. false true false work
8. false false true work
9. false false false work

Problem i dont know how combine :) tryed but dont worked :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a stringBuilder in conjunction with your checkbox checks.
for instance:

```
StringBuilder filter = new StringBuilder();

if(a.checked)
   filter.Append("filter here");

if(b.checked)
    filter.Append("filter here");

views.RowFilter= filter.toString();
```

Comment: Good idea :) But how build optimized, IF statement, for my all 3 checkbox. Then i can start think about filter.

Comment: This is how you combine the filters. filter in this scope is simply a StringBuilder (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) that houses the filter arguments until it is assigned to the RowFilter

Comment: I get error on multiple search Syntax error: Missing operand after '[Kateg.]' operator. Whe i search uncheck and search again, maybe i need somethink clear ???

Comment: Could you please paste the code that is giving you that error?

Comment: `if (checkBox1.Checked)
                {
                    filter.Append("[Produkta nosaukums] like '%" + textBox3.Text.ToString() + "%'");
                    //views.RowFilter = "[Produkta nosaukums] like '%" + textBox3.Text.ToString() + "%'";
                }
                if (checkBox2.Checked)
                {
                    filter.Append("[Kateg.] like '%" + comboBox4.Text.ToString() + "%'");
                    //views.RowFilter = "[Kateg.] like '%" + comboBox4.Text.ToString() + "%'";
                } views.RowFilter = filter.ToString();`

Comment: String builder declared at form start. If i run only 1 check box, check1 or check2 it work, but only once, if i change from check2 to check 1 then i get error. And i cant filter when check1 and check 2 is checked. Some error

Comment: Now I understand. What you need to do is check the string before each filter and if it is null or empty add 'and' to the string

Comment: 1 Problem solved at start i put `filter.Clear();` But my code dont filter when check 1 and check 2 is checked.

Comment: That clears the stringbuilder which would defeat the whole purpose. The reason you were getting the error is because you where appending the string without specifying the next rowfilter.

You should be adding **and** if the string is null or empty

Comment: I tested at start, and both filters was full, i get error. Or where you think i should put this and ???
I can feel answer is so close :) But my brain cant combine problem :/

Comment: if (checkBox1.Checked) 
    { 
      filter.Append("[Produkta nosaukums] like '%" + textBox3.Text.ToString() + "%'"); 
    } 
    if (checkBox2.Checked)  
    {  
      if (filter != null)
         filter.Append(" and "); 
   
      filter.Append("[Kateg.] like '%" + comboBox4.Text.ToString() + "%'"); 
    }

Comment: How i tested.
check1 checked, and put product name
check2 checked i select category, and then only BUTTON pressed. Both filters has arguments, but i get error. Maybe i need somehow put "+"

Comment: Almost work :)
I put you code like this. But i get error, when only checkbox2 checked and i want only category. I get error Syntax error missing operand before and.
`if (checkBox2.Checked)
                {
                    if (filter != null)
                    {
                        filter.Append(" and ");
                    }
                    filter.Append("[Kateg.] like '%" + comboBox4.Text.ToString() + "%'");
                    //views.RowFilter = "[Kateg.] like '%" + comboBox4.Text.ToString() + "%'";
                }`

Comment: try using filter.Length > 0 instead of filter!=null

Comment: I dont know why, but if only check 2 checked, This code use..if (filter != null)